# Is there an actual *formula* to get the y intercept of a line from 2 points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need an arithmetic function to calculate the y-intercept of a line from two points. The signature looks something like this:

$$
\huge f(\kern.1emp_1,\,p_2)=\overbrace{\hphantom{Lorem ipsum}}^\text{some formula}
$$

Is there a simple way of doing this easily, e.g. in a graphing calculator?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @angryavian I haven't had any ideas on what to try at all, hence why I didn't list anything.

Comment: Your question sounds a little like you know a difficult way to do it and you're asking for a better and easier way. But this is not the case?

Comment: @Arthur No. I can do it fine manually on paper, but it's a bit more difficult for me to think of in a formulaic situation

Comment: Ok, cool. That's exactly the kind of thing angryavian was asking about. How would you do it on paper? Please edit your question to include your favorite approach. We can then help you to polish that into a more streamlined process.

Answer (score 5):

If $p = (a,b)$ and $q=(c,d)$ then the line between them has equation
$$
(y-b)(c-a) = (x-a)(d-b)
$$

Set $x=0$ and solve for $y$ to get your formula for the $y$ intercept in terms of $a,b,c,d$.

(Answer only because you seem just to be using math, not studying it.)